# Election link missing from the main site

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, election

I noticed yesterday that the election link is no longer featured on the main site. Is this [status-by-design]? As far as I remember, this link has been present on all SE sites that underwent election until their conclusion.

The link is still present on meta, though.

**Edit**: [Link to the meta.SO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79644/election-link-missing-from-tex-se-main-site)

Comment: I'm getting a strange sense of deja vu.  Didn't we have this question yesterday?  And I remember a few "me too" comments confirming it.  But now I can't find that question.  Oh, and "me too": I can't see it either.

Comment: @Andrew: Yeah, I saw exactly the same thing but for the life of me I can't find it now. Besides, this will get the attention of the Powers That Be. (**edit**: here it is http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/943/2011-community-moderator-election/959#959)

Comment: @Martin: Great, this is much better as a question. Maybe even better: Post the same over at meta.SO, linking here?

Comment: @Hendrik: Good idea. Added the cross-post links as well

Comment: Right now, the election link is back.

Comment: The funny this is: I started to be annoyed by it and as soon it was gone I missed it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got an answer from the meta.SO question:

> This is by design. Election notice only lasts for 48 hours after the start of each phase on the parent site, but you'll notice that you still have one on the Meta site. If your pro tems are up for it, they can re-enable the system message, but this is typically discouraged. Keep in mind, also, that during the final election phase, there is also a pop up banner given to all eligible voters to pester them, and it does not time out like the system message does. – **Grace Note**

Comment: Given that we were a bit slow in getting this election started, I'm in favour of keeping the banner on the front page.  As it's now under mod-control, we could tune it a little.  Maybe something like "Only 4 days left to take control of this site: nominate yourself Right Now."

Comment: @Andrew: And this from someone who stated " I'm not and am not going to be a candidate." ;-)

Comment: @lockstep: Just because _I_ don't want to be a mod doesn't mean I don't want to have lots of fun throwing mud at those brave enough to volunteer.

Comment: @lockstep: All that aside, I'm pleased to see that you've thrown your hat in to the ring.  I think that having lots of people nominate themselves is a sign that the site is healthy and that people care about keeping the site working.